# hide all tables inside a div except the table before an inner div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following markup inside my web application :-

[image]

So i want using jquery,javascript, etc to do following:-

- Hide All tables that are inside the Div with id = `ctl00_PlaceHolderLeftNavBar_ctl02_WebTreeView`
- But Except the table that comes just before the inner div with id = `ctl00_PlaceHolderLeftNavBar_ctl02_WebTreeViewn10Nodes` , and also to show the inner div.

so in my above picture to hide everything except the "HR" and its sub-links "knowledge Type" & "Security"..
Can anyone adivce on this please?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have ids and you're using jQuery, [prev](https://api.jquery.com/prev/) should help.
Something like this should do it:

```
jQuery('#ctl00_PlaceHolderLeftNavBar_ctl02_WebTreeView').children('table').hide();
jQuery('#ctl00_PlaceHolderLeftNavBar_ctl02_WebTreeViewn10Nodes').prev('table').show();
```

[Here's a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/383ndjds/) with a simplified html structure.

Comment: but this will not have any effect .. now i am using jquery 1.10.2

Comment: now when i try this " #ctl00_PlaceHolderLeftNavBar_ctl02_WebTreeView  > table { display: none !important;} " it will hide all the table ,, but trying this "jQuery('#ctl00_PlaceHolderLeftNavBar_ctl02_WebTreeView').children('table').hide();" will not have any effect ,,,

Comment: Added a fiddle using that code which seems to work. Did I misunderstand what you need it to do?

Comment: now even if i only write this "jQuery('#ctl00_PlaceHolderLeftNavBar_ctl02_WebTreeView').children('table').hide();" it will not have any effect,, while if i write the following  " #ctl00_PlaceHolderLeftNavBar_ctl02_WebTreeView > table { display: none !important;} " it will hide all the tables..

Comment: Ahh perhaps there's some other style conflicting with it then.